# My login and register route are suddenly "NOT FOUND" IN MY LARAVEL PROJECT, But they have been working well, all other routes are still working well

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-routing

```
<ul class="nav-list">
    @if (Route::has('login'))
        @auth
            @if (Auth::user()->role === 1)
                <li><a href="">{{ Auth::user()->name }}</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{ route('dashboard.index') }}">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                       onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">Logout</a>
                </li>
                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                </form>
            @else
                <li><a href="">{{ Auth::user()->name }}</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                       onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">Logout</a>
                </li>
                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                </form>
            @endif
        @else
            <li><a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a></li>
            @if (Route::has('register'))
                <li><a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
            @endif
        @endauth
    @endif

</ul>
```

That's an excerpt of my nav.blade.php component. The login/register.blade.php files are in the "auth" folder. I am not sure what triggered the error. Thank you for any possible solutions.

Comment: first of all check that the routes exists ```php artisan route:list```

Comment: @MohammedNaguib yes the routes exist, thank you for the hint.

Comment: I later found out one of my routes had to be moved below other routes, that was the issue. But Im not sure why the route affected the auth routes.